# redirect to http to https for multiple domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

We have server having 2 domains

1) exmaple.co

2) exmaple.com.au

If User hits first domain "example.co"

`http://www.exmaple.co` OR `http://exmaple.co` then it should be redirect to

`https://exmaple.co`

If User hits second domain "example.com.au"

`http://www.exmaple.com.au` OR `http://exmaple.com.au` then it should be 
redirect to

`https://exmaple.com.au`

We have purchase SSL.

We have use framework Codeigniter set the coding in htaccess.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^exmaple.co [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://exmaple.co/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^exmaple.com.au [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.exmaple.com.au/$1 [L,R=301]
```

If i use above code then it's goes on redirect loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting infinite redirect loop because you are not preventing the redirect to happen at all.

To achieve what you are trying to do:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.co$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.co/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com\.au$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com.au/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(example\.com\.au|example\.co)$
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

This rule will redirect :

- http://example.co
- http://www.example.co
- https://www.example.co

or

- http://example.com.au
- http://www.example.com.au
- https://www.example.com.au

to https non-www